# Convert mat to GML file

Tags: matlab, graphics, type-conversion, gml, gephi

I want to visualise in [Gephi](http://gephi.org/) an adjacency matrix that is saved in .mat file. How can I convert an adjacency matrix that is saved in a .mat file to a GML file? I do not have access to Matlab.

Comment: one possibility would be to use another language . e.g. using python  import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('myfile.mat') and use networkx to create the graph and export it in a format that gephi understands. You can also use R matlab package

Comment: @user1043144 Thanks a lot. GML file was opened in txt format and I can convert it easily.I have problem with visualising such big 5k*5k graph now. Unfortunately,I'm not familiar with both R and Python. Do you think R and Python can help me and do you suggest to install and learn them for this purpose?

Comment: my suggestions were about to get to a format that gephi can read. You have now a GML file that gephi can read. No need for Python or R. Play around with layout in gephi (e.g. force atlas, repulsion strength 10.000 etc ...)